# Updating the saved password using system password

Tags: windows, browser, passwords

Is it possible to update a password saved in a browser to my windows login password everytime i change it.

I have a web application that uses my domain system username and password.

If I autosave the password i have to change it every 30 days or so.

Will it be possible to make a script or having any add on installed in any browser, that checks the windows login password and updates the password of the stored web page.

Comment: Is this better suited to SuperUser?

Comment: Also - which browser?

Comment: @Liath any browser preferably IE

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. Many websites allow you to log in using domain credentials however what you're looking for is to auto-populate those credentials in a webform.

To do this would require giving your web browser access to you windows security account which is a major security risk.